# Difference between "mad" and "angry"

Tags: differences, adjectives

Are there any differences between *mad* and *angry* and when should you use one instead of the other?

Comment: Try a good dictionary - for example, Wiktionary has great entries for [mad](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mad#English) and [angry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/angry#English) that cover their similarities and address other meanings of *mad*, such as the American English use in *mad skills* or *mad good answer*.

Comment: I disagree with the banner "this question is too basic".

Answer (score 7):

I think this may be closed for general reference, but they are synonyms mainly in American English, with *mad* being more colloquial than *angry*. I would never use *mad* in formal writing. In British English, *mad* exclusively means "insane" or "crazy," so it is not interchangeable with *angry*.

Comment: ... except that American English is a strong influence on British English, so stock phrases like "Don't get mad, get even" are widely used and understood by Britons.

Comment: Spot on. There's also in the U.S. a penchant for use of the word _mad_ to connote of simply _zany_ or _off the wall_, that is, as humorous. For a long time there was a comic book titled simply _MAD_ which was centrally defined by the antics of the perpetually youthful Alfred E. Newman. Then more recently we see the advent of _Mad TV_, always a series of skits intended to make light of some aspect of human nature, draw to the forefront some manner of social absurdity, etc., ever as cheeky as Benny Hill.

Comment: We also  see a shift in meaning from the noun *madcap* (originally a lunatic) to the adjective: *marked by capriciousness, recklessness, or foolishness* (m-w)